# How to detect if AirPlay is active before playing a video with AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, arrays, avplayer, airplay, mpremotecommandcenter

I was using the following code to detect whether or not AirPlay is the current selected route:

```
let airPlayActive = AVAudioSession
  .sharedInstance()
  .currentRoute
  .outputs
  .first?
  .portType == .airPlay
print("AirPlay active: \(airPlayActive)")
```

However, that doesn't work in a very specific scenario. My use case is knowing that air play is selected before playing a video. I have two view controllers, say **A** and **B**. For testing purposes, I have a timer on **A** that prints if AirPlay is active every second using the code above.

From **A**, I present modally view controller **B**, which basically plays a video using `AVPlayer` and controls the current selected route using a `MPVolumeView`. If I present **B**, waits for the video to play and then change the route to AirPlay, I can see that change being reflected on **A** (it will start printing `true`). Then, if I close **B** and then reopens it, it's possible to tell if AirPlay is active even before playing the video, and that's exactly what I want.

But there's a scenario where this doesn't work, though.

The scenario is (as weird as it may seem), if I add targets to remote commands using `MPRemoteCommandCenter`, that behavior I described above simply changes! Here's how I'm adding the targets (in view controller **B**):

```
let center = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
let pauseCommand = center.pauseCommand
pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
pauseCommand.addTarget(handler: { _ -> MPMPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
  // ... doing some business logic
  return .success
})
```

I am also removing that target in **B**'s `deinit`:

```
let center = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
let pauseCommand = center.pauseCommand
pauseCommand.isEnabled = false
pauseCommand.addTarget(nil)
```

Well, this just messes entirely with all AirPlay related stuff:

1. If I activate AirPlay on view controller **B** and then dismiss it, AirPlay gets deactivated. Now current `portType` becomes `.builtInSpeaker` again. Thus, I can not tell if AirPlay is active before reopening **B** (playing the video).
2. Even though `portType` is `.builtInSpeaker` after closing **B**, I still get `true` if I call `MPVolumeView().isWirelessRouteActive`, which tells me that a wireless route is active, but that's not necessarily AirPlay (it could be a Bluetooth headphone, for instance).
3. If I reopen **B**, `portType` goes from `.builtInSpeaker` to `.airPlay` after the video starts playing.
4. The audio route change notification also stops working properly. When observing `AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification`, it doesn't trigger sometimes and when it does, the user info at `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey` most of the times is `.unknown`.

For me, this is clearly a bug on Apple side, but would any of you happen to know an alternative? I basically need to know if AirPlay is active before playing the video.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround. It's as weird as the issue itself, but it's working...

I just added a target to a remote command right before playing video on view controller **B**. Then I just wait for a audio route change notification (or a timeout in case is not active). That signals it is "safe" to play the video.